# Shrub ID - East Texas

Tags: identification

I am trying to identify a shrub growing in my garden of my new home - east of Dallas.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to tell from that photo but it looks like nandina. It should have clusters of green berries that will turn red in late fall and are eaten by birds. Here ( Houston area) the berries are now starting to turn red. In zone 8 they hold leaves all winter and are invasive. Here, they grow to 8 feet. A plant will send up several stalks.

Comment: Could be although I have not seen any berries. 

Added 2 more pics in case that helps?

Comment: Not much help; could be nandina that was sheared ; the berries would have been on the tips. Could be other things in there like Ligustrum ( larger , shiny leaves). I don't want to be politically incorrect , but it looks like random , oversize shrubbery that was trimmed to put the house on the market. Some neighbors could likely tell you what is there. Also, TX had some record cold last winter that killed many plants for the first time ever, that may had an affect.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

That is definitely Nandina, sometimes called "holy Bamboo". I've seen this invasive plant take large areas away from native and adapted plants here in Tx. I don't consider it attractive, avoid planting it, and remove as much as possible whenever possible.

Comment: That answer has already been given.